# Is it possible to change the CPU specification of a VM created with a slurm cluster in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cpu, slurm

The core and capacity of the slurm cluster VM created on GCP were set too low.

I would like to change to a higher specification.

However, unlike general VMs, slurm has a total of 3 VMs.

1. image
2. controller
3. login

I'm wondering which of these three things I need to change to apply to slurm .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Three types of VMs](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp) will be created like you said

```
1 - controller node
N - login nodes
Multiple partitions with their own machine type, gpu type/count, disk size, disk type, cpu platform, and maximum node count.
```

Now go to Menu >compute engine > VM instance > go inside each one and look at the Observability tab. This will give you an indication of which VM is starving for resources.

Also you may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-slurm-cluster-compute-engine) for how the architecture is set up, and from diagram it looks like you want to give more power to the Compute Vms.

Comment: Are you saying that I can change the CPU specs for each VM individually?

Comment: Tried from the [marketplace](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp/blob/master/MP_README.md) solution, it seemed possible.

Comment: I've modified the CPU specs for all 3 VMs, and this seems to be working fine.
Thank you for the reply.